# Why does Windows 10 switch the Language, but not the Keyboard layout on Alt + Shift?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am a German Windows 10 user and I use both English and German Keyboard Layouts - German for writing texts and English for programming (because German Umlauts and English Special Characters share the same location).

I switch between these languages / layouts frequently, often without thinking about it using `Alt + Shift`.

A few days ago, the feature seemed to stop working. Alt + Shift does switch between languages, but not in the way I expected it:

The language bar shows "DEU" and when I switch it shows "ENG DE". Clicking on the language bar shows three configurations installed:

[image: Three Combinations of Language and Keyboard]

It shows:

- DEU (Deutsch / Deutsch-Tastatur)
- ENG US (English / US-Tastatur)
- ENG DE (English / Deutsch-Tastatur)

When

Switching using Alt + Shift, the System switches between DE and ENG-DE, which is not what I want. I have no idea how ENG-DE was installed, or where this combination is comming from.

- How do I remove the ENG-DE Language-Layout Combination?
- How do I make Alt+Shift switch between DE / EN, and not some other combination?

Comment: ALT-Shift controls the language, CTRL-Shift controls the layout.

Comment: I don't understand the difference. What does windows consider the "language" in this context?

Comment: The language is the primary indicator, which is shown by the DEU/ENG. Each language can have multiple layouts. The layouts are keyboard layouts (for example that you can use the right alt+r to give an ® right alt+s for ß, etc. Your keyboard will have these written as text on the keyboard itself. If you just want to switch between layouts, make sure it is set to ENG us or ENG de, and switch using CTRL-Shift to toggle between the two.

Comment: Why does language EN have a DE layout set? Where do I remove it?

Comment: Settings -> Time and Language -> Language. Select language, then press options. Hard to miss really.